# How to move a Javascript <script> that was placed after an </html> tag in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, security, malware

I have a Wordpress site that I inherited and I am getting a malware warning in SiteGround.

MATCHED: http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/warning.html_anomaly?2
<script>jQuery('.gform_wrapper ul li.gfield').removeClass('gfield');

I don't know the history of the site so i don't know where this script came from.

Looking at my page's source code I see this:

```
 ...</body></html></main> <script>jQuery('.gform_wrapper ul li.gfield').removeClass('gfield');

        jQuery(window).bind("load", function () {
            jQuery('.product-tab .common-tab').each(function () {

                var highestBox = 0;
                jQuery('.common-tab-box', this).each(function () {

                    if ($(this).height() > highestBox)
                        highestBox = $(this).outerHeight();
                });

                jQuery('.common-tab-box', this).height(highestBox);

            });

            jQuery('.tab-click').on('click', function () {
                jQuery(this).addClass('active-tab').siblings().removeClass('active-tab');
                jQuery('.common-tab').hide();
                jQuery('#tab-section-' + $(this).data('target')).fadeIn('fast');
            });

            jQuery('.tab-click').first().click();

        });

        function addBoxshadowToMenu() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 0) {
                $("nav.navbar").addClass('has-shadow');
            } else {
                $("nav.navbar").removeClass('has-shadow');
            }
        }

        mobilecheck = function () {
            var check = false;
            (function (a) {
                if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true;
            })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
            return check;
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            addBoxshadowToMenu();
            window.onscroll = function () {
                addBoxshadowToMenu();
            };
            if (mobilecheck()) {
                jQuery(".mounting-section .mouting-header p").find('br').remove();
                jQuery(".video-section .container .header p").find('br').remove();
                jQuery(".contact-section .container .section-content h2").find('br').remove();
            }
        });</script>
```

Upon reading about this warning, it looks like I need to move the javascript before the /html tag.

Questions:

1. Is this malware?
2. How do I move this script?  I looked at the file manager for this site and I can't find the file that would allow me to move this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If they truly injected malware its likely there is also a backdoor into your website, the script your linking in here is not malware, however if there is malware injected in the website, i would recommend either beginning from scratch with a new website, or have a specialized company remove the malware.

edit: Perhaps  you can link your website so i can check out the sourcecode

Comment: Thank you.  Here is the site:  https://www.lumigrow.com/

Comment: Hello Cecilia, I had a look at the source of your website and i don't see anything strange in the code. There is only 2 warnings in sucuri.net that i can see.

Website Monitoring
This seems to be a tool provided by sucuri used to monitor the status of your website (and warn you in case of trouble) https://sucuri.net/malware-detection-scanning/

and 
Website Firewall
This refers to a firewall for your website to protect you against hackers attacking your website https://sucuri.net/website-hack-protection/

So no malware as far as i can see

Comment: Thanks so much Jasper!  I really appreciate it!